# SignalR: Unable to call Hub method from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-mvc-controller

**Environment:**

- Visual Studio 2017 Community with latest updates
- Target Framework: .NET Core 2.1 (latest version)
- SignalR Core
- Running on IIS Express on Windows 10 (dev environment)

**TL;DR:** Injecting IHubContext<> into Controller ctor so Action method can send message to clients doesn't seem to be working.

**Long version:**

I have a basic ASP.NET Core test application working and .NET clients are able to connect and send/receive messages.  So my Hub and Clients appear to be working fine.

I'm now trying to add a controller to the same VS project that the SignalrR Hub is in so that external actors can send messages via a REST API endpoint.

To do this I've tried using DI to inject IHubContext<> into the **ctor of my controller** as follows:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private IHubContext<OrgHub> _hubContext;
    public ValuesController(IHubContext<OrgHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    //...

}
```

This appears to be successfully injecting the right IHubContext because when I debug the private members I see the number of connections = 1 when I have 1 .NET client connected.

**Now the trouble:** within an action method I try to use the _hubContext to call a hub method... but nothing happens.  The debugger passes by the line of code and no breakpoints within my Hub are hit.  Nothing happens at all. Note that when .NET clients send messages (via the SignalR .NET client) the breakpoints on my Hub are indeed hit. Its just the _hubContext in my Controller/action method that doesn't seem to be working.

Here is what I'm doing in an **action method**:

```
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>> GetAsync()
    {

        //Try to call "SendMessage" on the hub:
        await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("SendMessage", "SomeUserName", "SomeMessage");

       //...

        return new string[] { "bla", "bla" };
    }
```

And here is the corresponding **Hub method**:

```
 public class OrgHub : Hub
{

    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }

    //...

}
```

If it helps, here is the edited version of **Startup.cs**:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddSignalR();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();


        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<OrgHub>("/rpc");
        });


        app.UseMvc();


    }
}
```

So, any ideas or suggestions on where to go from here? Clearly there must be something I'm overlooking...

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how this works. When you call `SendAsync` that message is going out to the client. You don't call methods on your hub, via `SendAsync`. Nothing is happening, because the clients are literally getting sent a message that should invoke something listening for "SendMessage" *client-side*, which presumably is not something you've register your clients to listen for. If the goal is to hit "ReceiveMessage" client-side, then you should be doing `SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", ...)` in your controller.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there any way to call methods on the hub from the controller? I have some basic logic in there that I'd rather not duplicate in the controller.  I suppose I could extract it all into a class library.  For my own knowledge however is there any way to call a hub method and have this work as I was trying to do?

Comment: No. That's not what they're for. Methods on your hub are for *clients* to call. Think of them the same way you do `subscribe` calls on the client. Those are your hooks for the server, just like the methods on your hub are your hooks for the client.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Now that .NET 7 ISingleClientProxy.InvokeAsync is out, how would one keep track of the connectionIds from e.g., a controller? Because it requires connectionId to send a request to the client, it doesn't really fit in the context of the server would to request data from one or all client(s) at an arbitrary time. Could one save connection ids in a controller, backgroundService or any other place outside of Hub?